# Image not showing in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextview

I am trying to show selected image from library inline with text inside my `TextView`. I got this code from here, the programs runs without error. However, the selected picture doesn't show up in the `TextView`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

This is what I got so far:

// MARK: Camera Button

```
 @IBAction func camera(_ sender: Any) {

        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
        pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true

        self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    // MARK: show selected inmage in textview
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: AnyObject]) {

        // get image from libary
        if let libraryImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

            var attributedString :NSMutableAttributedString!
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:notesTextView.attributedText)
            let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
            textAttachment.image = libraryImage

            //textView
            let oldWidth = textAttachment.image!.size.width;
            let scaleFactor = oldWidth / (notesTextView.frame.size.width - 10);
            textAttachment.image = UIImage(cgImage: textAttachment.image!.cgImage!, scale: scaleFactor, orientation: .up)
            let attrStringWithImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
            attributedString.append(attrStringWithImage)
            notesTextView.attributedText = attributedString;

        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: If you use the debugger to step through this, do you see the attributed strings being created?

Comment: @ Phillips the only thing I saw is this line: [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error. I don't see anything about creating strings.